# Standard Marketing Cloud Profile Center to update Salesforce Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, profile, marketing-cloud-connect, preference-center, profile-center

I am using the standard SFMC Profile Center with Salesforce integrated (Fields mapped) to manage profile attributes and preferences.
When a contact modifies his attributes on this profile center, the information doesn't update in the Contact Preference Related list.
I wonder how to proceed but I have created a data extension with all the attributes existing in All Subscribers list and another data extension with the old and new fields respectively such as `FirstName_New` and `FirstName_Old`.
I setup a first automation SQL activity to retrieve the Data from the contact into my first DE:

```sql
SELECT 
  c.Id                              AS [Subscriber key], 
  c.BT_ContactEmail__c            AS [Email Address], 
  c.FirstName                       AS [Prénom], 
  c.LastName                        AS [Nom],
  c.Birthdate                       AS [Date de naissance],
  c.MailingStreet                   AS [Numéro et nom de la voie],
  c.MailingPostalCode               AS [Code postal],
  c.MailingCity                     AS [Ville],
  c.MailingCountry                  AS [Pays],
  c.BT_Newsletter__c                AS [Abonnement Newsletter],
  c.BT_ShopNewsletter__c            AS [Abonnement Newsletter Boutique ],
  c.BT_PartnerNewsletter__c         AS [Abonnement Newsletter Partenaire],
  c.BT_EmailMagazine__c             AS [Magazine format numérique],
  c.BT_PostalMagazine__c            AS [Magazine format papier],
  c.BT_EmailAppeal__c             AS [Emails Appel aux Dons]
FROM 
  [Contact_Salesforce] c 
LEFT JOIN 
  _Subscribers s ON c.Id = s.SubscriberKey 
LEFT JOIN 
  _EnterpriseAttribute ea ON s.SubscriberId = ea._SubscriberID
WHERE 
  (
    COALESCE(c.FirstName, '') <> COALESCE(ea.[Prénom], '') 
    OR COALESCE(c.LastName, '') <> COALESCE(ea.[Nom], '') 
    OR c.BT_ContactEmail__c <> s.EmailAddress
  ) 
  AND c.BT_ContactEmail__c IS NOT NULL 
  AND c.LastModifiedDate > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

I placed a verification activity and wonder how to do next to get the info in the second data before setting up a Data Extract, a File Transfer and an Import Activity.
Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice way to map attributes across SFMC and SFDC is to use a properly configured Marketing Cloud Connect implementation.

See documentation here: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/mc_co_implementation_guide.pdf

See page 24 for "Map Attribute Fields". Also note that SFMC's Subscriber Key needs to reflect the SFDC Contact/Lead ID, which can be a blocker for existing SFMC instances.

I can see that you have progressed down a different route of solution design in your question, however I want to provide this best-practice suggestion in case you hadn't considered it.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I've used this document to connect Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud and mapped the fields.